# SSLSocket Connection trust certificate

Tags: android, ssl, certificate

I'm currently developing an Android application on which I need to do a SSLSocket Connected to a test server.

Thing is we won't buy a certificate for this server since it is a test server, not production.

While it works fine on Simulator, however on my S3 it gives me this error :

```
06-01 00:36:17.355: I/System.out(13629): java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

The exception is throws by the last line of this code :

```
mSf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
mSocket = (SSLSocket) mSf.createSocket("myTestingServer.com", 443);
mSocket.startHandshake();
```

I don't really care that the solution is either code or lower the security check as an Android user, since it is to test on my S3, once in production, the certificate should be good.
This is not a HTTP server, so I can't use org.apache.http.org.ssl

Comment: check your expiration date and time it is too old please set it properly and try.

Comment: Not really my question, I do not have access to the server right now, I can't change anything on it. I just need to connect regardless the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to ignore the certificate check

**Warning : this code is not safe**

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }
}};

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = sc.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("google.com", 443);
...
```

Source : [Using Java to connect with SSLSocket, trusting all certificates](https://blog.alcor.se/index.php/2013/08/09/using-java-to-connect-with-sslsocket-trusting-all-certificates/)